# How can I schedule apex to run every 30 seconds?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

We wanted to create an outbound message queue system that would process requests individually and in order to any external web service. The frequency that these requests should be processed is variable but as an example, it might be that we would like the process to run once every 30 seconds.

It is not possible or practical to schedule the same job 120 times for every 30 seconds within the hour.

The approach I finally settled on was to chain schedule apex (wait until scheduled time, call future method and delete (abort) itself) -> future call (process request if there is one and reschedule class to rerun in 30 seconds) -> schedule apex (call future method in 30 seconds, abort itself) -> future call (process request and reschedule) and so on indefinitely. The end result has been running on production for 2 weeks now but has just failed to reschedule itself and I do not understand why.

I believe what is happening is that I am breaching some kind of governor limit but I don't understand how. I have been having similar issues more frequently on my sandbox and have received a limit exception stating that the limit for future requests has been exceeded.

From the point that the service failed, I queried for all asynchronous jobs (not just future) from the previous 24 hours and it returned just 2200. I believe this figure should be 4400 because I think the schedule jobs are not showing up (The scheduled jobs abort themselves after they call the future method).

Even so, Salesforce states that we are allowed 250,000 asynchronous apex executions every 24 hours so I don't understand what is going on. Does anyone have any experience trying to chain scheduled jobs in this way? Is there a better way to achieve this? Is there a limit that I am not aware of or am I measuring asynchronous executions in the wrong way?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you can try better luck on [salesforce stackexchange site](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I once was reasonably successful in getting Apex to do this at a granularity of 5 minutes, not 30 seconds, but in any case there is an inherent fragility to this method.  @future calls do not have a guaranteed run time, so while they commonly run immediately upon invocation, they can be delayed.  I have experienced delays as large as 20 minutes in executing @future methods, so that might explain why you have less scheduled runs than you thought (although the fact that it is exactly half what you expected is puzzling).

What it comes down to is that, at least as of this writing, Scheduled Apex just isn't really made for this use case.  In my case I ended up using the [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) as an intermediary.  I realize that's not the ideal solution (it's a different platform, different language, still Force.com though), but it's more robust.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment is awaiting moderation.

Hi,
Please check the below points.
1. This is a DML Statement, which has a governing limit of 10,000.You are updating your batch at the end, and not on each iteration.

Put “LIMIT 9999″ on the end of your query. If this works then this is your issue.Use
database.executebatch(new SyncCalendarsUpdates (), 1);
2. Please check instance “Data Storage” Got to Setup>> Monitor >>System Overview (DATA STORAGE)
Solution Please delete some data or contact to salesforce increase the data storage limit.